# reversing string using pointers in c

Tags: c, string, runtime-error

its a program to reverse a string however its giving some error likely due to 
the **printf** statement in the end. please help with the error
I'm a newbie to pointers so please tell me if my conversion of pointer to array is not right?

```
void reverse(char *a)
 {   char *b;
    int j=0;
     int l=strlen(a);
      l--;

    while(l>=0)
      { b[j]=a[l];
         l--;j++;
       }
      b[j]='\0';
      printf("%s",b);
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to implement `reverse()`, depending on whether the string that is passed into the function is to be modified or not.

If the only purpose is to print the string in reverse order, rather than to change the storage, then you could use:

```
void print_reverse_string(const char *str)
{
    const char *src = str + strlen(str);
    while (src > str)
        putchar(*--src);
}
```

If the goal is to reverse the string in storage and print it, then you could use:

```
void reverse_string_and_print(char *str)
{
    if (*str == '\0')
        return;
    char *src = str;
    char *end = src + strlen(src) - 1;
    while (end > src)
    {
        char t = *end;
        *end-- = *src;
        *src++ = t;
    }
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

The second function is badly designed because it does two jobs.  It would be better to have a `void reverse(char *str)` function that reverses a string in situ, and then print it from the calling code.

```
void reverse(char *str)
{
    if (*src == '\0')
        return;
    char *src = str;
    char *end = src + strlen(src) - 1;
    while (end > src)
    {
        char t = *end;
        *end-- = *src;
        *src++ = t;
    }
}
```

This could claim to be a general-purpose function in a way that `reverse_string_and_print()` cannot.

Note that the test for an empty string avoids undefined behaviour (UB) when subtracting 1 in the expression for `end`.  The chances of it hurting are small, but UB should be avoided at all times.

---

#### SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_reverse_string(const char *str)
{
    const char *src = str + strlen(str);
    while (src > str)
        putchar(*--src);
}

void reverse_string_and_print(char *str)
{
    char *src = str;
    char *end = src + strlen(src) - 1;
    while (end > src)
    {
        char t = *end;
        *end-- = *src;
        *src++ = t;
    }
    printf("%s", str);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char fixed[] = "Hello World!";
    print_reverse_string(fixed);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("%s\n", fixed);
    char data[] = "Hello World!";
    reverse_string_and_print(data);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("%s\n", data);
    return(0);
}
```

#### Example output

```
$ ./rv
!dlroW olleH
Hello World!
!dlroW olleH
!dlroW olleH
$
```

Comment: Thanks! that was quite insightful.
although i'm still have a doubt that between 
char *b=(char *)malloc (sizeof(char)*strlen(a+1));
and
char b[strlen(a)+1];
which is a better initilization and in which cases?

Comment: If you use `malloc()`, you must know where you do the matching `free()`.  If you use the C99 VLA, you don't have to worry about freeing the space.  If you're going to return the string from the function (`char *reverse(const char *str)`), then you must use `malloc()` because you can't return a pointer to a local string (but then the calling code must call `free()`).

Answer (score 5):

```
char *b;
```

You never allocated any memory for the pointer `b`. You must point this pointer to a memory big enough to hold the string you are copying to it. Note that this results in Undefined behavior, so it might even appear to work in some cases but nevertheless it is not guaranteed to work.

You might point the pointer to an local array or allocate it memory using `malloc`. The former is preferable, especially since you never actually return anything from the function.You need a string just local to the function only.

Comment: Given that the input is non-constant, you could do the string reversal in situ without needing auxilliary storage.  If the string was not to be modified, the argument would be `const char *a`, and the function name would be `print_reversed_string(const char *a)` or thereabouts.  In C99, you could use `char b[strlen(a)+1];` to allocate a VLA — variable-length array.

Comment: char *b=(char *)malloc(size of(a));? is this the right implementation to initialize the pointer b? #Alok Save

Comment: Not `sizeof(a)`; `strlen(a)+1`!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes thanks its running now..whats the difference in allocating the array with char b[strlen(a)+1]; and using char *b=(char*)malloc(size of (a+1))? is the latter implementation void here?

Comment: `sizeof(a)` gives you size of the pointer `a`, which is not what you are really asking for. What you need is size of the the string, which is length of the string + 1 extra space for null terminator, hence `strlen(a)+1`